# Roslyn error only with .NET Core: "ResolvePackageFileConflicts" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

My code is responsible for get types namespaces using Roslyn API based on solution file path; before i find out namespaces, i get the documents with:

```
using (var ws = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
{
    var solution = await ws.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    
    //[...] some code

    var diagnostics = ws.Diagnostics;

    //[...] some code

    return solution.Projects.SelectMany(p => p.Documents);
}
```

When i pass as parameter some solution file path from a .NET Framework solution, the code works fine. But when i pass as parameter some solution file path from a .NET Core solution, the variable `diagnostics` gets some errors (one for each project inside the solution):

> *Msbuild failed when processing the file '`[project's .csproj file]`'*
> *with message:*
> *C:\Program\Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ConflictResolution.targets:*
> *(39, 5): The "ResolvePackageFileConflicts" task failed unexpectedly.*
> *System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly*
> *'NuGet.Versioning, Version=5.6.0.5, Culture=neutral,*
> *PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.*

Both solutions (.NET Core and .NET Framework) compile correctly. Do i have to setup some specific configuration when i'm analyzing .NET Core projects with Roslyn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce this while loading [Nodatime](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) with a .Net Core 3.1 project. In order to solve it you can add the following `NuGet` package references to your solution:

- NuGet.Frameworks
- NuGet.Packaging
- NuGet.ProjectModel
- NuGet.Versioning

Comment: Now it work's perfectly, thanks! How did you find out this?

Comment: I've tried to load Nodatime to see if I get a similar message and I did. Next, I was just following the error message. It was complaining that the mentioned packages are missing (one by one). What it bothers me now is that I don't know for sure why are they needed and I plan to take a look when I get some time.